# Pie Chart transparency, multiple Pies

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, transparency, pie-chart

I would like to stack two pie charts ontop each other. The idea here is then to make one of them smaller so you only can see a outer ring of the pie chart behind. I tried using:

```
chartCalProgres.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
chartCalProgres.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

But as you can see in the link below, it did not work. Anyone have an idea to how this effect could be achieved?

[Pie Charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyVsa.jpg)

[Should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFzB7.jpg)

Comment: Are those charts just two bitmaps or are they dynamically generated?

Comment: Dynamically generated, and they will change when using the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with Pie charts, but you can get it done rather nicely with the ChartType.Doughnut:

[image: two-ringed doughnut]

Here are the steps:

1 We need to have two Series and two ChartAreas

2 We need to control the Position, the Size and the InnerPlotPosition of the CAs. They must overlay and have the right sizes..

3 We also need to control the DoughnutRadius of the two Series we use. This is the inner radius.

4 Finally we need to set the Backcolor of the inner Series to Transparent.

Here is the code that set up my example:

```
    using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
    //..

    Random R = new Random(); //Added to allow code to work
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    Series S1 = chart1.Series.Add("Pie1");
    Series S2 = chart1.Series.Add("Pie2");

    chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();

    ChartArea CA1 = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("Outer");
    ChartArea CA2 = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("Inner");

    CA1.Position = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 100);
    CA2.Position = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 100);

    float innerSize = 60;
    float outerSize = 100;
    float baseDoughnutWidth = 25;

    CA1.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition((100 - outerSize) / 2,
            (100 - outerSize) / 2 + 10, outerSize, outerSize - 10);

    CA2.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition((100 - innerSize) / 2,
            (100 - innerSize) / 2 + 10, innerSize, innerSize - 10);

    S1["DoughnutRadius"] = 
     Math.Min(baseDoughnutWidth * (100 / outerSize), 99).ToString().Replace(",", ".");
    S2["DoughnutRadius"] = 
     Math.Min(baseDoughnutWidth * (100 / innerSize), 99).ToString().Replace(",", ".");
    

    S1.ChartArea = CA1.Name;
    S2.ChartArea = CA2.Name;

    S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Doughnut;
    S2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Doughnut;

    CA2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    S1["DoughnutRadius"] = "41"; // leave just a little space!
    S2["DoughnutRadius"] = "99"; // 99 is the limit. a tiny spot remains open

    // test data, optional, R is a Random instance
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        S1.Points.AddXY(i, 42 - R.Next(44));
        S2.Points.AddXY(i, 77 - R.Next(88));
    }
}
```

Note the strange way to set the DoughnutRadius; also note that many numbers inside a chart are percentages of the chart controls sizes..!

I found the code [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/3c0bb720-517f-4bdc-a573-4b612e813cfb/creating-2d-grouped-doughnut-chart-in-c), all kudos to fireblade123, Escener Technologies!!